# Calculating the root-mean-square-error between two matrices one of which contains NaN values

Tags: matlab, interpolation, mean

This is a part of a larger project so I will try to keep only the relevant parts (The variables and my attempt at the calculations)

I want to calculate the root mean squared error between Zi_cubic and Z_actual

[RMSE formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UINRr.png)

Given/already established variables

```
rng('default');

% Set up 2,000 random numbers between -1 & +1 as our x & y values
n=2000;
x = 2*(rand(n,1)-0.5);
y = 2*(rand(n,1)-0.5);
z = x.^5+y.^3;

% Interpolate to a regular grid
d = -1:0.01:1;
[Xi,Yi] = meshgrid(d,d);



Zi_cubic = griddata(x,y,z,Xi,Yi,'cubic');
Z_actual = Xi.^5+Yi.^3;
```

My attempt at a calculation

My approach is to

1. Arrange Zi_cubic and Z_actual as column vectors
2. Take the difference
3. Square each element in the difference
4. Sum up all the elements in 4 using nansum
5. Divide by the number of finite elements in 4
6. Take the square root

```
D1 = reshape(Zi_cubic,[numel(Zi_cubic),1]);
D2 = reshape(Z_actual,[numel(Z_actual),1]);
D3 = D1 - D2;
D4 = D3.^2;
D5 = nansum(D4)
d6 = sum(isfinite(D4))
D6 = D5/d6
D7 = sqrt(D6)
```

Apparently this is wrong. I'm either mis-applying the RMSE formula or I don't understand what I'm telling matlab to do.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language is this? You've included lots of unnecessary tags, but not the most important one: the language you're using.

Comment: Matlab, changed the tags, sorry about that.

Comment: There is also a [`nanmean`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nanmean.html), or if you have a newer version of MATLAB you can do `mean(A,'omitnan')`.

Comment: But why do you say this is wrong? Do you get an unexpected result? Do you get a NaN output? Does your result not match some pre-conceived notion of the result?

Comment: When I submit the assignment via matlab grader it says "incorrect value for rms_cubic". All the results up to that point are correct according to matlab grader. I sent an email to the instructor and am awaiting a response. He doesn't tell us what the correct value is in matlab grader.

Comment: Just a small tip. For Step 1, i.e. arranging the matrices to column vectors, you could simply use (:). E.g. D1=Zi_cubic(:);

Answer (score 1):

Your RMSE is fine (in my book). The only thing that seems possibly off is the meshgrid and griddata. Your inputs to griddata are vectors and you are asking for a matrix output. That is fine, but you're potentially undersampling your input space. In other words, you are giving n samples as inputs, but perhaps you are expected to give n^2 samples as inputs? Here's some sample code for a smaller n to demonstrate this effect more clearly:

```
rng('default');

% Set up 2,000 random numbers between -1 & +1 as our x & y values
n=100; %Reduced because scatter is slow to plot
x = 2*(rand(n,1)-0.5);
y = 2*(rand(n,1)-0.5);
z = x.^5+y.^3;

S = 100;
subplot(1,2,1)
scatter(x,y,S,z)

%More data, more accurate ...
[x2,y2] = meshgrid(x,y);
z2 = x2.^5+y2.^3;

subplot(1,2,2)
scatter(x2(:),y2(:),S,z2(:))
```

The second plot should be a lot cleaner and thus will likely provide a more accurate estimate of Z_actual later on.

I also thought you might be running into some issues with floating point numbers and calculating RMSE but that appears not to be the case. Here's some alternative code which is how I would write RMSE.

```
d = Zi_cubic(:) - Z_actual(:);
mask = ~isnan(d);
n_valid = sum(mask);

rmse = sqrt(sum(d(mask).^2)/n_valid);
```

Notice that `(:)` linearizes the matrix. Also it is useful to try and use better variable names than D1-D7.

In the end though these are just suggestions and your code looks fine.

PS - I'm assuming that you are supposed to be using `cubic` interpolation as that is another place you could perhaps deviate from what's expected ...

Comment: Thanks Jimbo, I spoke with the instructor and he said my calculation was right. It seems that stack exchange recommends that I keep this question up instead of deleting it.